# AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'videoCapture' 2022

Tags: python, module, attributes, video-capture

I am facing 'cv2' has no attribute 'videoCapture' error. I have updated the latest python-pip version. Here is my code..

```
import cv2 as cv

capture = cv.videoCapture('videos/cat1.mp4')

while True:
    isTrue, frame = capture.read()
    cv.imshow('video', frame)

    if cv.waitKey(20) & 0*FF == ord('d'):
        break

capture.relase()
cv.destroyAllWindos()
```

[Terminal error shows here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJZTV.png)

Comment: it would be easy if you shared what all you tried to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

It's not `cv.videoCapture('videos/cat1.mp4')` but should `cv.VideoCapture('videos/cat1.mp4')`

Comment: Thanks. but now it showing


 File "h:\practice\read1.py", line 18, in <module>
    if cv.waitKey(20) & 0*FF == ord('d'):
NameError: name 'FF' is not defined

Comment: change ```if cv.waitKey(20) & 0*FF == ord('d'):``` to ```if cv.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('d'):```